# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "por más que" y "por menos que"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

He visto ambas formas, que parecen significar "however" en inglés, pero no entiendo la diferencia entre las dos. ¿Alguien puede aclarar esta cuestión?

Answer (score 5):

Estas dos expresiones no significan lo mismo.

### Por más que

***Por más que*** transmite el mismo significado que *aunque* o *sin importar que* ("regardless of the fact that" en inglés, o también "no matter how much", o "however" en su sentido paralelo a "[who|when|what]ever)", etc.). Por ejemplo:

> *No voy a dejarte por más que me lo pidas.*
> = *No voy a dejarte aunque me lo pidas.*
> = *No voy a dejarte sin importar que me lo pidas.*
> = "I'm not leaving you no matter how much you ask."
>
> *Por más que el precio baje nadie va a comprarlo.*
> = *Aunque el precio baje nadie va a comprarlo.*
> = *No importa cuánto baje el precio, nadie va a comprarlo.*
> = "However much the price is lowered, no-one will buy it."

Nótese que en la traducción al inglés "however much" equivale más bien al español *sin importar cuánto*. No hay mucha diferencia en este caso pero al final haré una aclaración.

### Por menos que

Entretanto, ***por menos que*** equivale a *sino* o *hacer otra cosa que* (en inglés, "but"). Es una frase idiomática que se usa sólo con el verbo *poder* en negativo, así:

> *No puedo por menos que estar de acuerdo con eso.*
> = *No puedo sino estar de acuerdo con eso.*
> = *No puedo hacer otra cosa que estar de acuerdo con eso.*
> = "I cannot but agree with that."

Dependiendo del dialecto, se puede omitir el *por*. Por ejemplo, yo diría simplemente:

> *No puedo menos que lamentarme.*
> = "I cannot but regret (it)."

### Por más que vs. por mucho que

Una aclaración final: *por más que* y *por mucho que* son sinónimos y muchas veces pueden usarse intercambiablemente, pero no siempre. La diferencia es la siguiente:

- *por más que* equivale a *sin importar que* o *sin importar si*, es decir, en inglés, "no matter whether"
- *por mucho que* equivale a *sin importar cuánto*, es decir "no matter how much"

Es decir que da aproximadamente lo mismo decir estas dos frases:

> *Por más que llores…*
> *Por mucho que llores…*

(en inglés la traducción más natural sería "No matter how much you cry…")… pero no es lo mismo decir estas dos:

> *Por mucho que ganes…*
> *Por más que ganes…*

La primera se traduciría como "No matter how much you win/gain…" pero la segunda sería "Regardless of whether you win…". La pequeña diferencia de significado hace que el verbo *ganar* adopte uno u otro sentido.