# ¿Cuál es el origen de la conjunción «si bien»?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, conjunciones

La frase *«si bien»*, que significa básicamente "aunque", funciona como una conjunción, pero sus partes no parecen tener relación alguna con su significado. ¿Cuál es su origen, cuál es el razonamiento semántico detrás de la unión de estas dos palabras? Echando una mirada al CORDE parece que existiese desde por lo menos el siglo XVII. ¿Desde cuándo la recoge alguna fuente académica con el significado actual?

Aunque no tiene que ver directamente con la etimología castellana, también me llama la atención que lo que llamo "razonamiento" detrás de la idea se encuentra en al menos otros dos idiomas. En inglés se usa a veces *if* "si" con el significado de "aunque", y en alemán, increíblemente, existe la conjunción *obwohl* "aunque" formada transparentemente por *ob* "si" + *wohl* "bien" (cognada del inglés *well*).

P.S.: Se acaba de ocurrir también que *«si bien»* tiene cierto parecido semántico con otra frase conjuntiva similar: *«[por más que](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-por-m%C3%A1s-que-y-por-menos-que)»* (o también *«por mucho que»*), que también significa "aunque". El *por* introduce una hipótesis o condición y el *más* o *mucho* son adverbios que indican tendencia positiva o abundancia, como *bien*. Dejo esto como aporte a quien quiera intentar una respuesta.

Comment: No sé de donde viene pero es el mismo término en francés: si bien.

Comment: Mira, lo encontré el El Quixote año, 1605: Y más, que no habrá quien se ponga a averiguar si los seguistes o no los seguistes, no yéndole nada en ello. Cuanto más que, **si bien caigo en la cuenta**, este vuestro libro no tiene necesidad de ninguna cosa de aquéllas que vos decís que le faltan, porque todo él es una invectiva contra los libros de caballerías, de quien nunca se acordó Aristóteles, ni dijo nada San Basilio, ni alcanzó Cicerón; http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ESL0027/_P2.HTM#1II

Comment: @Lambie Buen hallazgo, aunque no estoy seguro de que signifique lo mismo (no tiene sentido adversativo como "aunque").

Comment: Según el foro del Instituto Cervantes si bien es igual que aunque: una persona dice:" 'Si bien', equivalente a 'aunque', es nexo que introduce la subordinada adverbial concesiva que se subordina a otra oración llamada principal." La frase se Cervantes parece ir "por allí"...

Comment: En la segunda parte de la _General Estoria_ de Alfonso X está este trozo: _Et **si bien** auie de ser, que lo dixiesse como quier: si quier publica mientre, si quier en poridat_. No logro entender el significado y es probable que no coincida con el moderno. Es del siglo XIII.

Comment: También en italiano: _[sebenne](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/sebbene)_.

Comment: En francés *si bien* quiere decir *muy bien*, nada que ver con el significado actual en castellano.

Comment: Si bien es aunque, también. C'est si bien=Está muy/tan bien. Si bien que =aunque.

Comment: @Lambie no, *si bien que* es expresión de consecuencia, como en castellano sería *de modo que* https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si_bien_que

Comment: Pregunta de seguimiento: Como llegó "cual si" significar "como si"?

Comment: @rsanchez Ha dicho: "En francés si bien quiere decir muy bien," Esto no es cierto. En todo caso, es la misma ***forma***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo, el primer registro en un diccionario de la locución adverbial *si bien* está en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, de 1739 (tomo S-Z):

> SI BIEN. Modo adverbial. Lo mismo que aunque. Usase contraponiendo una cosa à otra, ò para explicar alguna excepcion en la especie de que se habla.

No indica su posible origen. Buscando textos en el CORDE, efectivamente aparecen algunos de principios del siglo XVII que usan la locución (negritas mías en los ejemplos sucesivos):

> *[...] porque el poder del duque de Lerma va siempre en aumento, y así por esto como por haberse hablado en el Senado de este caballero, dos y mas veces, pasaré á tratar de los que asisten en la Córte, concluyendo que **si bien** se entiende que el Rey no ama mucho á don Cristóbal, le desterró mas el miedo del duque de Lerma, que el ódio del Rey, el cual ya que no le favoreciera, por lo menos no le apartara.*
>
> Anónimo, "Relación que hizo a la República de Venecia Simon Contareni", 1605 (España).

Pero podemos irnos más tiempo atrás:

> *Cuando el conde ermitaño supo la gracia que el Rey había concedido a su hijo, fue a su presencia, se arrodilló a sus pies y le besó la mano, **si bien** el Rey no se la quería dar, y le agradeció infinitamente el donativo que había hecho a su hijo.*
>
> Anónimo, "Traducción de Tirante el Blanco de Joanot Martorell", 1511 (España).

Mucho más difícil parece ya encontrar ejemplos en el siglo XV, dado que los textos parecen ser todos del tipo "si bien te fijas", equivalente a "si te fijas bien", por cómo se escribían los textos en aquella época. En todo caso, la *Nueva Gramática* comenta al respecto en el [párrafo 47.16m](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bGzzTVKHmlYkXlsY):

> El adverbio *bien* [...] es el primer constituyente de la locución *bien que* y el segundo de *si bien*. Aunque ambas han sido consideradas calcos del francés o del italiano, se ha señalado en los estudios sobre estas construcciones que [...] *si bien* se usa desde el siglo XV, antes del período de influencia italianizante.

Y efectivamente, hacia finales del siglo XV hay algunos casos, como este que aparece en un documento notarial de 1497:

> *[...] y por parte del dicho Pero Martinez se dize que porque jamas en tiempos passados la dicha ciudad puso consol ni fue admetido por essa Senyoria, **si bien** algunas vezes ha intentado lo mismo que agora, y ciertos embaxadores de la dicha ciudad de Barcelona, que aqui de presente se fallan, pretienden todo lo contrario [...].*

Me falta encontrar cómo se originó la locución, por aquello de que efectivamente parece una combinación extraña. Solo puedo especular con que frases como las del siglo XIV y principios del XV, que hacían gran uso de "si bien", generaran de algún modo una doble forma de entender la frase. No es un buen ejemplo, pero pongamos lo siguiente:

> *Respondió Crito: "Nosotros ternemos en cuidado aquestas cosas que dizes. Mas dime ¿cómo mandas que te enterremos?"
>
>   Respondió Sócrates: "Como quisieres, que **si bien** me havéis entendido, yo non me apartaré de vosotros."*
>
> Pero Díaz de Toledo, "Traducción del Libro llamado Fedrón, de Platón", 1446-1447 (España).

La respuesta se entiende como "si me habéis entendido bien", pero a lo mejor se podría interpretar como "aunque me habéis entendido, yo no me separaré de vos". Que sí, que no es el mejor ejemplo y está un poco forzado, pero no encuentro un ejemplo mejor ahora mismo.

Comment: También se usa en el portugués (*se bem*), gallego (*se ben*), y asturianu (*si bien*, curiosamente solo admite *bien* y no *bono*), aragonés (*si bien*).

Comment: No entiendo "por aquello de efectivamente parece una combinación extraña".

Comment: @aparente001 ¡arreglado!

Comment: Gracias; perdón, ahora encontré otra duda, no tengo confianza para editar la frase que empieza con "Solo puedo especular ".

Answer (score 3):

No he conseguido encontrar ninguna referencia, pero mi "teoría" es que viene de

> Si bien es cierto que

Me explico. "Si bien" es sinónimo de "aunque", la conjunción de las subordinadas concesivas por excelencia. Se parecen a las adversativas en la estructura `"aunque [concesión], resulta que [tengo razón yo]".`

Una manera formal y elegante de hacer esta "concesión" es justamente la frase que he puesto arriba:

"si bien es cierto que [...] resulta"

Pero por el momento esto no significa nada, pues el "si bien" sigue apareciendo junto.

La cosa es que también es frecuente oirlo sin el "si": `"Bien es cierto que..."`

Y el adverbio "bien" se usa muchas veces con el sentido de "muy": `está bien chulo`.

Así que "bien podría tratarse" de una evolución como esta

```
es bien cierto → bien es cierto → si bien es cierto → si bien
```

Así que hasta aquí mi elcubración. Espero que me rebatáis con cosas interesantes y así aprender de dónde viene de verdad ;-)